# How do I use this purple disc item?

Tags: dungeons-3

In dungeons 3, one of the last mission of the campain (19/20 where u sacrifice titans), I've found a purple disc in a dragon nest saying "Stronger dungeonheart" (100% to 400% stronger).

How do I use this ? It looks like a spell because of the range, but it is not listed as a spell in the almanach, and it's not activated when I drop it on dungeon heart.

I have to say in the end of mission, my dungeon was 29 000 instead of 10 000, and then a bit later, it was 20 000, no clue what could have activated the disc if it's what happened, because no snort would pick it up.